# Nintex Edit Page, Editting a webpart show an empty page

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow

I am editing a form using Nintex. I want to show a list from another form in my form, but I need the list updated (I can do ajax auto refresh for the list on its own page). I have the list in my form as a webpart, when I click edit the webpart, it show nothing, just a page with my form title. Could someone help me please?

Comment: can you please explain a bit more that what you want to achieve? you can have `list view` in you Nintex form, how are you doing 'edit webpart' on a nintex form. this is confusing

Comment: you can edit webpart from a form. My goal is I can have a form, with a webpart below it (which the list is keep updating). I already have a form with a webpart below it, I want the webpart list keep updating(ajax). It can be done with "edi webpart", but when I click it, it shows an empty page.